# How to create C macro name using another macro?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have been given a library that defines the following macros:

```
#define FOO_0(A, B) (A + B)
#define FOO_1(A, B) (A - B)
```

Now I'd like to create a new macro `MY_FOO` that takes a third argument `x` and use it build the name of the macro to be called (e.g. `FOO_<x>`)

Here is my experiment:

```
#define MY_FOO(X, A, B) FOO_## X ##(A, B)
```

However, when I try to use it in my code:

```
int main(void) {
    int a = 2, b = 3, x = 0;
    printf("FOO_%d(%d, %d) = %d", x, a, b, MY_FOO(x, a, b));
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:6:25: error: pasting "FOO_x" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
 #define MY_FOO(X, A, B) FOO_## X ##(A, B)
                         ^
prog.c:11:41: note: in expansion of macro ‘MY_FOO’
  printf("FOO_%d(%d, %d) = %d", x, a, b, MY_FOO(x, a, b));
                                         ^~~~~~
prog.c:6:25: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘FOO_x’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 #define MY_FOO(X, A, B) FOO_## X ##(A, B)
                         ^
prog.c:11:41: note: in expansion of macro ‘MY_FOO’
  printf("FOO_%d(%d, %d) = %d", x, a, b, MY_FOO(x, a, b));
                                         ^~~~~~
```

Is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: The second `##` is not required.

Comment: In C, there should never be a need to create macros with completely variable names. Macro names are for the programmer, not for the program. If you somehow come up with such a need still, you should rather run an external script that generates the C code.

Comment: Generating the code proposed by @bipll in the post below automatically could actually be a very good idea because I have to use the same pattern for a lot of macros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need to turn run-time values into macro names, you'll have to do it on your own:

```
switch(x) {
    case 0: printf("FOO_0(%d, %d) = %d", a, b, FOO_0(a, b));
            break;
}
```

You can even make it slightly more advanced with local syntax-defs:

```
switch(x) {
#define CASE(x) case x: printf("FOO_" #x "(%d, %d) = %d", a, b, FOO_ ## x(a, b)); \
                        break
    CASE(0);
#undef CASE
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The distinction between run-time and compile-time value is probably the key to this problem.

Comment: Even more than that, macros are parse-time values, before the compilation itself. :)